# Jquery - Field value flickers after resetting the form

Tags: jquery, onclick, flicker

I am running this function below:

```
    $('.cancelbutton').click( function() {


    $('#gform2').attr('action','/ajax/add.php');
            $('input[name=aid]').val('0');
            $('.cancelbutton').hide();

            var reset_formdate = $('#adate').val();

            $('#gform2')[0].reset();            
            $('input[name=adate]').val(reset_formdate);

        });
```

The issue Im seeing is after this function is ran the value in in the field adate flickers at least 10-15 times. Any ideas why it would do that? Never seen this before. It doesnt matter what field I put a value in, if I add the value to the field after the reset command the value in that field flickers. When I mean by flickers I mean the value shows/hides really fast like its blinking. I ran Firebug in Firefox while this was happening and it doesnt show any additional calls being made. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. I had the function inside a js script that was being return via a ajax call. I moved the function to the page itself that was making the ajax call and now it doesnt flicker.